# Can mapEvery be implemented with foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

For a function that maps a function to every nth element in a list:

```
mapEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEvery n f = zipWith ($) (drop 1 . cycle . take n $ f : repeat id)
```

Is it possible to implement this with `foldr` like ordinary `map`?

EDIT: In the title, changed 'folder' to 'foldr'. Autocorrect...

Comment: I wouldn't expect so, not with a single foldr at least.

Comment: Hm? That's really interesting. How would you implement it with multiple `foldr`'s?

Comment: ...Never mind, don't think that'd work either.  With `foldr` you're only going to be able to count how many elements from the _end_ of the list you are, not how many from the beginning you are.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I was thinking that could work, if the base case includes `mod (length xs) n` but that only works for finite lists.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You can implement `foldl` in terms of `foldr`, so it really doesn't matter which fold you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one solution

```
mapEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEvery n f as = foldr go (const []) as 1 where
  go a as m 
    | m == n    = f a : as 1
    | otherwise =   a : as (m+1)
```

This uses the "`foldl` as `foldr`" trick to pass state from the left to the right along the list as you fold. Essentially, if we read the type of `foldr` as `(a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r` then we instantiate `r` as `Int -> [a]` where the passed integer is the current number of elements we've passed without calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can:

```
mapEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEvery n f xs
    = foldr (\y ys -> g y : ys) []
    $ zip [1..] xs
    where
        g (i, y) = if i `mod` n == 0 then f y else y
```

And since it's [possible to implement `zip` in terms of `foldr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235148/implement-zip-using-foldr), you could get even more fold-y if you really wanted.  This even works on infinite lists:

```
> take 20 $ mapEvery 5 (+1) $ repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2]
```

---

This is what it looks like with even more `foldr` and inlining `g`:

```
mapEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEvery _ _ [] = []
mapEvery n f xs
    = foldr (\(i, y) ys -> (if i `mod` n == 0 then f y else y) : ys) []
    $ foldr step (const []) [1..] xs
    where
        step _ _ [] = []
        step x zipsfn (y:ys) = (x, y) : zipsfn ys
```

Now, would I recommend writing it this way?  Absolutely not.  This is about as obfuscated as you can get while still writing "readable" code.  But it does demonstrate that this is possible to use the very powerful `foldr` to implement relatively complex functions.