# Why Haskell doesn't accept my combinatoric "zip" definition?

Tags: haskell, fold

This is the textbook zip function:

```
zip :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
zip [] _ = []
zip _ [] = []
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zip xs ys
```

I asked on #haskell earlier wether "zip" could be implemented using "foldr" alone, no recursion, no pattern matching. After some thinking, we noticed the recursion could be eliminated using continuations:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
zip' = foldr cons nil
    where
        cons h t (y:ys) = (h,y) : (t ys)
        cons h t []     = []
        nil             = const []
```

We are still left with pattern matching. After some more neuron toasting I came up with an incomplete answer that I thought was logical:

```
zip :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zip a b = (zipper a) (zipper b) where
    zipper = foldr (\ x xs cont -> x : cont xs) (const [])
```

It returns a flat list, but does the zipping. I was certain it made sense, but Haskell complained about the type. I proceeded to test it on a untyped lambda calculator, and it worked. Why can't Haskell accept my function?

The error is:

```
zip.hs:17:19:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t0 ~ (t0 -> [a]) -> [a]
    Expected type: a -> ((t0 -> [a]) -> [a]) -> (t0 -> [a]) -> [a]
      Actual type: a
                   -> ((t0 -> [a]) -> [a]) -> (((t0 -> [a]) -> [a]) -> [a]) -> [a]
    Relevant bindings include
      b ∷ [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:7)
      a ∷ [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:5)
      zip ∷ [a] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:1)
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘cons’
    In the expression: ((foldr cons nil a) (foldr cons nil b))

zip.hs:17:38:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t0 ~ (t0 -> [a]) -> [a]
    Expected type: a -> (t0 -> [a]) -> t0 -> [a]
      Actual type: a -> (t0 -> [a]) -> ((t0 -> [a]) -> [a]) -> [a]
    Relevant bindings include
      b ∷ [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:7)
      a ∷ [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:5)
      zip ∷ [a] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at zip.hs:17:1)
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘cons’
    In the fourth argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘(foldr cons nil b)’
```

Comment: What's the error Haskell gives you?

Comment: If all you're stuck with is the pattern matching just use `(,)` as a function, and `head` and `tail` instead of (y:ys) and maybe an if/else?

Comment: It complains about not being able to construct an infinite type. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm creating a continuator which expects a continuator.

Comment: btw: a very similar question was asked some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235148/implement-zip-using-foldr

Comment: [Oleg did it, Oleg did it!](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/zip-folds.lhs)

Comment: FYI, I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885983/infinite-type-error-when-defining-zip-with-foldr-only-can-it-be-fixed/) to a follow-up question that could technically pass as an answer for this one too.

Comment: Well, I can only hope someone who understands Agda (one of the other 11 of you) benefits of it...! Heh. Certainly above my reach now. But I'm still amazed. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielWagner, I believe ski also did it, independently. And there was a paper about such things not too long ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to why your definition is not accepted: look at this:

```
λ> :t \ x xs cont -> x : cont xs
 ... :: a -> r -> ((r -> [a]) -> [a])

λ> :t foldr
foldr :: (a' -> b' -> b') -> b' -> [a'] -> b'
```

so if you want to use the first function as an argument for `foldr` you get (if you match the types of `foldr`s first *argument*:

```
a' := a
b' := r
b' := (r -> [a]) -> [a]
```

which of course is a problem (as `r` and `(r -> [a]) -> [a]` mutual-recursive and should both be equal to `b'` )

That is what the compiler tells you

### how to repair it

You can repair your idea using

```
newtype Fix a t = Fix { unFix :: Fix a t -> [a] }
```

which I *borrowed* form it [original use](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.0.1/docs/Data-Fix.html).

With this you can write:

```
zipCat :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipCat a b = (unFix $ zipper a) (zipper b) where
  zipper = foldr foldF (Fix $ const [])
  foldF x xs = Fix (\ cont -> x : (unFix cont $ xs))
```

and you get:

```
λ> zipCat [1..4] [5..8]
[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

which is (what I think) you wanted.

**BUT** obvious here both of your lists needs to be of the same type so I don't know if this will really help you

Comment: Use of `Fix` is equivalent to using general recursion or a fixpoint combinator, so I think this is at odds with OP's "no recursion" criterion.

Comment: @AndrásKovács quite possible yes (although you could argue about types vs. function or that `foldr` might be recursive too, ...) - do you see another way to get the compiler to accept the OP's `zip` that don't stray away to much from the code?

Comment: I haven't looked at OP's code yet... As to `foldr`, it's about as non-recursive as it can get, since it corresponds to both Church encoded lists in System F (and everything provably terminates there), and the computation rule for lists in type theory.

Comment: @AndrásKovács tbh: I think this is not the place to argue but AFAIK `foldr` is still [implemented](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-Foldable.html#foldr) in a recursive fashion (in Haskell) - but again that's not really the point here is it?

Comment: It kinda is, actually, but I'm impressed you managed to type it.

Comment: @AndrásKovács (and the others...) Hi, I've added a new answer, maybe you'd like to check it out. It uses a simpler recursive type (`t` is actually redundant), and Haskell already has recursive types, so I don't need to think about "Fix" myself!

Answer (score 2):

We can eliminate the explicit pattern matching by defining a function that will do it for us.

Is it cheating? Not if [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) and [`bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool) are allowed, as they are; then we should also allow [`list`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:list) (also in [`extra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra)'s `Data.List.Extra`),

```
list :: b -> (a -> [a] -> b) -> [a] -> b 
list n c []     = n
list n c (x:xs) = c x xs
```

just the same; so that we can have, in your `zip'` definition,

```
cons h t = list [] (\y ys -> (h,y) : t ys)
```

or e.g.

```
         = list [] (uncurry ((:).(h,).fst <*> t.snd))
         = list [] (curry $ uncurry (:) . ((h,) *** t))
         = list [] (flip ((.) . (:) . (h,)) t)
         = list [] ((. t) . (:) . (h,))
```

if you prefer this kind of thing.

About your error, "infinite type" often indicates self application; indeed, whatever your `zipper` returns, you're self-applying it, in your

```
zip a b = (zipper a) (zipper b)  where ....
```

---

I tried to tweak your definition and came up with

```
zipp :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipp xs ys = zip1 xs (zip2 ys)
  where
     -- zip1 :: [a] -> tq -> [(a,b)]          -- zip1 xs :: tr ~ tq -> [(a,b)]
     zip1 xs q = foldr (\ x r q -> q x r ) n xs q 
                       -------- c --------
     n    q  = []

     -- zip2 :: [b] -> a -> tr -> [(a,b)]     -- zip2 ys :: tq ~ a -> tr -> [(a,b)]
     zip2 ys x r = foldr (\ y q x r -> (x,y) : r q ) m ys x r  
                         ---------- k --------------
     m  x r  = []

{-
  zipp [x1,x2,x3] [y1,y2,y3,y4]

= c x1 (c x2 (c xn n)) (k y1 (k y2 (k y3 (k y4 m))))
       ---------------       ----------------------
        r                     q

= k y1 (k y2 (k y3 (k y4 m))) x1 (c x2 (c xn n))
       ----------------------    ---------------
        q                         r
-}
```

It seems to reduce correctly on paper, but still I got the infinite type errors here too.

There is no (immediately apparent) self-application now, but the type of the continuation that the first zip gets, depends on the type of that first zip itself; so still there's a circular dependency: `tq` is on both sides of the type equivalency in `tq ~ a -> tr -> [(a,b)] ~ a -> (tq -> [(a,b)]) -> [(a,b)]`.

Indeed that's the two type errors that I get, (the first one is about the `tr` type),

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t1 ~ (a -> t1 -> [(a, b)]) -> [(a, b)]          -- tr

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t0 ~ a -> (t0 -> [(a, b)]) -> [(a, b)]          -- tq
```

In the usual definitions using `foldr` with continuations, the type of those continuations is independent; that's the reason that it works there, I guess.

- See also my [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944707/849891) here, and [this follow-up Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29885983/849891)

Answer (score 2):

I can offer you a slightly different perspective (I think) to arrive at a similar solution as Carsten's (but with simpler types).

Here's your code again, for your "weaving zip" (I'm writing `tr` for "the type of `r`", similarly `tq` for "the type of `q`"; I always use "`r`" for the *recursive result* argument of combining function in `foldr` definitions, as a mnemonic device):

```
zipw :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipw xs ys = (zipper xs) (zipper ys) where
    zipper xs q = foldr (\ x r q -> x : q r) (const []) xs q
                        --- c -------------- --- n ----

 -- zipper [x1,x2,x3] (zipper ys) =
 -- c x1 (c x2 (c x3 n)) (zipper ys)
         --- r --------  --- q -----  tr ~ tq ; q r :: [a]
                                      --     => r r :: [a]
                                      -- => r :: tr -> [a] 
                                      --   tr ~  tr -> [a]
```

So, this is the infinite type. Haskell doesn't allow this for an arbitrary type (which is what type variables stand for).

But Haskell's datatypes do actually admit recursion. Lists, trees, etc. — all the usual types are recursive. This *is* allowed:

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Here we *do* have the same type on both sides of the equation, just as we have `tr` on both sides of the type equivalency, `tr ~ tr -> [a]`. But it's a specific type, not an arbitrary one.

So we just declare it so, following the above "equation":

```
newtype TR a = Pack { unpack :: TR a -> [a] } 
           -- unpack :: TR a -> TR a -> [a]
```

What's a `Tree a` type? It's "something" that goes into a `Branch`, which is a `Tree a`. A given tree doesn't have to be infinitely constructed, because `undefined` has type `Tree a` too.

What's a `TR a` type? It's "something" that goes into `TR a -> [a]`, which is a `TR a`. A given `TR a` doesn't have to be infinitely constructed, because `const []` can be of type `TR a` too.

Our wannabe recursive type `tr ~ tr -> [a]` has become bona fide recursive type definition `newtype TR a = Pack { TR a -> [a] }`, hiding behind the data constructor, `Pack` (which will be gotten rid of by the compiler, thanks to the `newtype` keyword being used, but that's an extraneous detail; it works with `data` too).

Haskell handles the recursivity for us here. Type theoreticians love to deal with this themselves, with `Fix` and whatnot; but a Haskell user already has this available to them, in the language. We don't have to understand how it is implemented, to be able to use it. No need to reinvent the wheel until we want to build it ourselves.

So, `zipper xs` had type `tr`; now it becomes `TR a`, so this is what the new `zipper xs` must return — the "packed" list-producing function. The `foldr` combining function must return what the `zipper` call returns (by the virtues of `foldr` definition). To apply the packed function we now need to `unpack` it first:

```
zipw :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipw xs ys = unpack (zipper xs) (zipper ys)
    where
    zipper :: [a] -> TR a
    zipper = foldr (\ x r -> Pack $ \q -> x : unpack q r)
                   (Pack $ const [])
```

Comment: nice - yeah the `t` is redundant - tbh: I just used the quick `copy&paste` the compiler output and `Fix` it solution ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig thanks; :) I thought to use this insight in the other problem; no luck for  now. the types are more complex...

Comment: yeah guess so - but it should be really easy to translate [a,b,c,d,e] -> [(a,b),(c,d),...] and mix in some ADT (Either comes to mind)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I got it! I define two mutually-recursive types: http://ideone.com/tgAK0A. Will post the answer shortly!!

Comment: nice - good work - but you should really not add yet another answer - just add it to the one you got - don't get me wrong you would get yet another upvote from me put some people here on SO really get pissed of at this stuff

Comment: @CarstenKönig I think it's ok to add second answer that is different; I think my answer is different enough from yours, mainly in the insight of turning type equivalency into recursive type definition. I couldn't make out what all that Fix stuff was/is. Also, it is a *long* answer. (and if you meant *my* other answer, it's long too) :) :) -- But what I meant, I'm adding it not here of course; but on my followup question.

Comment: no offense meant - I have no problem if you add another answer - it just looks strange to have 4 answers where 3 are from the same person - but congrats - good job

Comment: @CarstenKönig you're absolutely right about the three answers. and thanks! this was nice. :)

Comment: @CarstenKönig As I wrote there, the translation from type equivalencies to newtype definitions was purely mechanical. Maybe the compiler should be doing this for us, do you think? (though the types namespace would be littered... but it could use some garbled names there...)