# Infinite type error when defining zip with foldr only; can it be fixed?

Tags: haskell, types, fold

(for the context to this see [this recent SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879944/why-haskell-doesnt-accept-my-combinatoric-zip-definition)).

I tried to come up with the definition of `zip` using `foldr` only:

```
zipp :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipp xs ys = zip1 xs (zip2 ys)
  where
     -- zip1 :: [a] -> tq -> [(a,b)]          -- zip1 xs :: tr ~ tq -> [(a,b)]
     zip1 xs q = foldr (\ x r q -> q x r ) n xs q 
                       -------- c --------
     n    q  = []

     -- zip2 :: [b] -> a -> tr -> [(a,b)]     -- zip2 ys :: tq ~ a -> tr -> [(a,b)]
     zip2 ys x r = foldr (\ y q x r -> (x,y) : r q ) m ys x r  
                         ---------- k --------------
     m  x r  = []
{-
      zipp [x1,x2,x3] [y1,y2,y3,y4]

    = c x1 (c x2 (c xn n)) (k y1 (k y2 (k y3 (k y4 m))))
           ---------------       ----------------------
            r                    q

    = k y1 (k y2 (k y3 (k y4 m))) x1 (c x2 (c xn n))
           ----------------------    ---------------
           q                         r
-}
```

It "works" on paper, but gives two "infinite type" errors:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t1 ~ (a -> t1 -> [(a, b)]) -> [(a, b)]             -- tr

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t0 ~ a -> (t0 -> [(a, b)]) -> [(a, b)]             -- tq
```

Evidently, each type `tr`, `tq`, depends on the other, in a circular manner.

Is there any way to make it work, by some type sorcery or something?

I use  Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 with GHCi 7.8.3 on Win7.

Comment: Hi - I added the default-trick to the answer to your original question to show you how you could fix your `zip` there - you should be able to use this to get this working too (but you will have to puzzle quite a bit more with the types, definitions, etc.)

Comment: @CarstenKönig no matter; but won't I need _mutually_ recursive types here? is it much different from what you've added there? (btw I assumed the "weaving" instead of zipping in that OP's code was an error on their part)

Comment: I did not really try it and it might be easier to cheat the different types in there with an Either, use the strange `zipCat` and then just take it's output to `unzip` inline (if you get what I mean)

Comment: @WillNess that's actually what I wanted (equivalent to `(\a b -> concat (zipWith (\a b->[a,b]) a b))`), since I noticed it would look so good without the tuple constructor! Not really trying to implement `zip` but gain an insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying the insight from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944707/849891), I was able to [solve it](http://ideone.com/tgAK0A), by defining two mutually-recursive types:

```
-- tr ~ tq -> [(a,b)]
-- tq ~ a -> tr -> [(a,b)]

newtype Tr a b = R { runR ::  Tq a b -> [(a,b)] }
newtype Tq a b = Q { runQ ::  a -> Tr a b -> [(a,b)] }

zipp :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipp xs ys = runR (zip1 xs) (zip2 ys)
  where
     zip1 = foldr (\ x r -> R $ \q -> runQ q x r ) n 
     n = R (\_ -> [])

     zip2 = foldr (\ y q -> Q $ \x r -> (x,y) : runR r q ) m 
     m = Q (\_ _ -> [])

main = print $ zipp [1..3] [10,20..]
-- [(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)]
```

The translation from type equivalency to type definition was purely mechanical, so maybe compiler could do this for us, too!

Comment: Oh - that's awesome. Something I'd not be able to come up with, at all. Congratulations! :)

Comment: @Viclib Thanks a lot, for asking the question too!!

Answer (score 8):

My issue with using `Fix` to type `zipp` (as I pointed out in the comments to Carsten's answer to the [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879944/why-haskell-doesnt-accept-my-combinatoric-zip-definition)) is that no total language contains the `Fix` type:

```
newtype Fix a = Fix { unFix :: Fix a -> [a] }

fixList :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a]
fixList f = (\g -> f (unFix g g)) $ Fix (\g -> f (unFix g g))

diverges :: [a]
diverges = fixList id
```

This may seem to be an obscure issue, but it really is nice to have an implementation in a total language, because that also constitutes a formal proof of termination. So let's find a type for `zipp` in Agda.

First, let's stick for a while with Haskell. If we manually unfold the definitions of `zip1` and `zip2` for some fixed lists, we find that all of the unfoldings have proper types, and we can apply any unfolding of `zip1` to any unfolding of `zip2`, and the types line up (and we get the correct results).

```
-- unfold zip1 for [1, 0]
f0 k = []        -- zip1 []
f1 k = k 0 f0    -- zip1 [0]
f2 k = k 1 f1    -- zip1 [1, 0]

-- unfold zip2 for [5, 3]
g0 x r = []               -- zip2 []
g1 x r = (x, 3) : r g0    -- zip2 [3]
g2 x r = (x, 5) : r g1    -- zip2 [3, 5]

-- testing
f2 g2 -- [(1, 5), (0, 3)]
f2 g0 -- []

-- looking at some of the types in GHCI
f0 :: t -> [t1]
f1 :: Num a => (a -> (t1 -> [t2]) -> t) -> t
g0 :: t -> t1 -> [t2]
g1 :: Num t1 => t -> ((t2 -> t3 -> [t4]) -> [(t, t1)]) -> [(t, t1)]
```

We conjecture that the types can be unified for any *particular* combination of `zip1`-s and `zip2`-s, but we can't express this with the usual `foldr`, because there is an infinite number of different types for all the unfoldings. So we switch to Agda now.

Some preliminaries and the usual definition for dependent `foldr`:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List hiding (foldr)
open import Function
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Product

foldr :
    {A : Set}
    (B : List A → Set)
  → (∀ {xs} x → B xs → B (x ∷ xs))
  → B []    
  → (xs : List A)
  → B xs
foldr B f z []       = z
foldr B f z (x ∷ xs) = f x (foldr B f z xs)
```

We notice that the types of the unfoldings depend on the length of the to-be-zipped list, so we concoct two functions to generate these types. `A` is the type of the elements of the first list, `B` is the type of the elements of the second list and `C` is a parameter for the argument that we ignore when we get to the end of the list. `n` is the length of the list, of course.

```
Zip1 : Set → Set → Set → ℕ → Set
Zip1 A B C zero    = C → List (A × B)
Zip1 A B C (suc n) = (A → Zip1 A B C n → List (A × B)) → List (A × B)

Zip2 : Set → Set → Set → ℕ → Set
Zip2 A B C zero    = A → C → List (A × B)
Zip2 A B C (suc n) = A → (Zip2 A B C n → List (A × B)) → List (A × B)
```

We need to prove now that we can indeed apply any `Zip1` to any `Zip2`, and get back a `List (A × B)` as result.

```
unifyZip : ∀ A B n m → ∃₂ λ C₁ C₂ → Zip1 A B C₁ n ≡ (Zip2 A B C₂ m → List (A × B))
unifyZip A B zero    m       = Zip2 A B ⊥ m , ⊥ , refl
unifyZip A B (suc n) zero    = ⊥ , Zip1 A B ⊥ n , refl
unifyZip A B (suc n) (suc m) with unifyZip A B n m
... | C₁ , C₂ , p = C₁ , C₂ , cong (λ t → (A → t → List (A × B)) → List (A × B)) p
```

The type of `unifyZip` in English: "for all `A` and `B` types and `n` and `m` natural numbers, there exist some `C₁` and `C₂` types such that `Zip1 A B C₁ n` is a function from `Zip2 A B C₂ m` to `List (A × B)`".

The proof itself is straightforward; if we hit the end of either zippers, we instantiate the input type of the empty zipper to the type of the other zipper. The use of the empty type (⊥) communicates that the choice of type for that parameter is arbitrary. In the recursive case we just bump the equality proof by one step of iteration.

Now we can write `zipp`:

```
zip1 : ∀ A B C (as : List A) → Zip1 A B C (length as)
zip1 A B C = foldr (Zip1 A B C ∘ length) (λ x r k → k x r) (λ _ → [])

zip2 : ∀ A B C (bs : List B) → Zip2 A B C (length bs)
zip2 A B C = foldr (Zip2 A B C ∘ length) (λ y k x r → (x , y) ∷ r k) (λ _ _ → [])

zipp : ∀ {A B : Set} → List A → List B → List (A × B)
zipp {A}{B} xs ys with unifyZip A B (length xs) (length ys)
... | C₁ , C₂ , p with zip1 A B C₁ xs | zip2 A B C₂ ys
... | zxs | zys rewrite p = zxs zys
```

If we squint a bit and try to ignore ignore the proofs in the code, we find that `zipp` is indeed operationally the same as the Haskell definition. In fact, the code becomes *exactly* the same after all the erasable proofs have been erased. Agda probably doesn't do this erasure, but the Idris compiler certainly does.

(As a side note, I wonder if we could make use of clever functions like `zipp` in fusion optimizations. `zipp` seems to be more efficient than Oleg Kiselyov's [fold zipping.](http://okmij.org/ftp/Algorithms.html#zip-folds) But `zipp` doesn't seem to have a System F type; maybe we could try encoding data as dependent eliminators (induction principles) instead of the usual eliminators, and try to fuse those representations?)

Comment: Neat. Also, not sure why zipp would be more efficient.

Comment: @Viclib Oleg's version is O(n^2), while `zipp` is O(N). Actually, `zipp` and your `zip` really piqued my interest because I initially thought that it was impossible to do this in O(N), and I suspected the functions to be wrong somehow.  But alas, I managed to prove them OK in Agda. It's neat how your wacky untyped lambda term turned out to have a type. I think it could be worthwhile to further investigate `zipp` and other functions like it, I think there is more than meets the eye here.

Comment: at Oleg's link that you gave in your answer, he mentions a previous version of his, "with a recursive type". I think what he referred to is [this](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-October/016577.html). There's an `szip` function there, near the end; it looks like my code does something that is very similar to it.

Comment: and here's [another post from that thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-October/016693.html) discussing possible relevance of this to fusion optimizations for `zip`, as you mentioned.

Comment: If you have an induction principle, you can always emulate case expressions. And if you can emulate case expressions, zipping is [not a problem](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/stuff/Lists/zipWith-via-elim.agda).

Comment: @user3237465 that's the "standard" O(N^2) solution; the implementation in the question and my answer is O(N), which makes it rather more interesting, as I commented above.

Comment: No, it's O(n). `caseList` truly deconstructs a list, much like in the [PLists](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/stuff/Lists/PList.hs) approach, which is a mix of [Church and Scott encoding](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/stuff/Lists/ChurchScott.hs). You can rewrite every function, that doesn't exploit the axiom K, using just eliminators. And it will have the same computational complexity (but you will need to rewrite functions like Berry’s majority in sequential form). That's what Epigram [did](http://strictlypositive.org/vfl.pdf).

Comment: @user3237465 my fault, that's O(n) indeed in Agda. I note though that by making use of the `{xs}` argument in `elimList`, you use it effectively as a paramorphism (repairing the asymptotics), and we can't translate that to an untyped lambda term that works on pure Church-encoded lists and runs in O(n).

Comment: In pure lambda calculus we can convert Church-encoded lists to Scott-encoded lists, zip and convert back. All operations are O(n). However there is no way to zip two lists in O(n) in pure system F, as [proved](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397591900395) by Loïc Colson.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Coming back to this answer 1 year later it makes more sense now... I almost get it. Just wondering, assuming that `self-types` system we discussed previously is strongly normalizing, then is the original solution using `fix` an acceptable answer here? I've posted a follow-up question on typing this in Morte.

Comment: Now you're making me wonder: what are the corresponding problem and solution for *coinductive* (potentially infinite) lists?

Comment: @dfeuer colists can be always zipped efficiently.

Comment: I mean... what's the equivalent of the "zip with `foldr` only" condition for colists? You can easily "unzip with `unfoldr` only" using the `unzip xs = (fmap fst xs, fmap snd xs)`, but maybe there's some more interesting analogue?