# Is it possible to type `min` in a normalizing theory such as System-F or the Calculus of Constructions?

Tags: haskell, types, agda, dependent-type, type-theory

This `min` definition below works on two church numbers and returns the least big. Each number becomes a continuation that sends its pred to the other, zig and zag, until zero is reached. Moreover, one of the numbers appends f to the result each time it is called, so, in the end, you'll have `(\ f x -> f (... (f (f x)) ...))` where the number of 'f's on the right is the number of times the first continuation was called.

```
min a b f x = (a_continuator b_continuator)
    a_continuator = (a (\ pred cont -> (cont pred)) (\ cont -> x))
    b_continuator = (b (\ pred cont -> (f (cont pred))) (\ cont -> x))
```

It seems like `min` can't be typed on System-F. For example, in order to run it on GHC, I had to use `unsafeCoerce` twice:

```
import Unsafe.Coerce

(#)   = unsafeCoerce
min'  = (\ a b f x -> (a (\ p c -> (c # p)) (\ c -> x) (b (\ p c -> (f (c # p))) (\ c -> x))))
toInt = (\ n -> (n (+ 1) 0))
main  = print (toInt (min'
    (\ f x -> (f (f (f (f (f x))))))               -- 5
    (\ f x -> (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f x))))))))))  -- 8
    :: Int)
```

Is it possible to type `min` on System-F (or the Calculus of Constructions)?

Comment: I can't parse `(cont -> x)`. Is there a `\ ` as well?

Comment: I have no clear idea here, but I think church numerals as having a _polytype_ `CN = forall a. (a->a)->a->a`. Since polytypes can't be inferred, I'd start by annotating numeral-valued variables with `CN` -- there's a chance you are using them at different types.

Comment: @chi Actually there shouldn't be a `\` on the other lambda. I had no idea how it got there. "There is a chance I'm using them at different types"?

Comment: In the untyped lambda calculus, you can apply a church numeral to any function. In a typed language with no polytypes, you can have a numeral for every type `T` (which can be applied to functions `T->T`, only) -- this limitation is however very inconvenient. In a polytyped language, you can assign type `CN` to numerals, so that they can work with any function of type `T->T`, whatever type `T` is.

Comment: After some experiment, I feel that the subterm `a (\ p c -> c  p)` can not be typed in SystemF (even after adding some type parameters). Its type seems to depend on the actual value of `a`. In CoC, I guess that it could be typed, but only after adding not merely type variables/type arguments, but other terms which encode how the resulting type depends on `a`.

Comment: This seems to work the similarly as the [coroutining zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885983/infinite-type-error-when-defining-zip-with-foldr-only-can-it-be-fixed) in the prior question, so I think it can be similarly typed in Agda. However, it would also use dependent elimination, this time on natural numbers, and there's no way to get that purely from Church encodings. We'd need to add the elimination rule to the base language.

Comment: That's what I'm asking actually. Your solution uses dependent eliminators, which CoC (thus, Morte) doesn't have. So you're saying it isn't typeable on CoC, right?

Comment: Right. It's somewhat bad news for those wanting minimal core languages. You could look into type theories with closed ("generic") type universes though, since they can be much more powerful than vanilla CoC but still have quite simple specification (and they also doesn't need any user-defined data types).

Comment: The way you said is hard to Google it. Could you give me some pointers, @AndrásKovács?

Comment: Unfortunately the material I read about this is scattered around many non-self-contained papers, and I don't remember anything from the top of my head that would be nice specifically for your purposes. The idea is to encode all types using a small set of constructions, for accessible basics you can look at `GHC.Generics` and its uses. For more advanced generic universes you can look at [this](http://www.andres-loeh.de/IndexedFunctors/) or [this](http://sneezy.cs.nott.ac.uk/darcs/Pig09/papers/icfp-2010-desc/icfp23l-dagand.pdf).

Comment: In general I learned lots from Conor McBride's papers (pigworker on SO and reddit) and on generics specifically from Anders Löh's papers (kosmikus on SO and reddit). Search on Google Scholar for their stuff. I guess you would need to take a deep type theory dive to get a good grasp on this. I recommend the experience wholeheartedly, though.

Comment: "I guess you would need to take a deep type theory dive to get a good grasp on this." - and how can I do that efficiently? When I consider doing that, what stops me is that I think I'd spend more time uncharting the field and figuring what I should read, than on reading itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95494/discussion-between-andras-kovacs-and-viclib).

Answer (score 4):

The function (is it well-known? it looks really clever) is typeable, it just doesn't work with Church-encoded nats.

Here is the type that GHC infers:

```
(((t3 -> t2) -> t3 -> t2) -> (b0 -> a0) -> t1 -> t0)
                        -> (((t6 -> t5) -> t6 -> t4) -> (b1 -> a0) -> t1)
                        -> (t5 -> t4)
                        -> a0
                        -> t0))
```

Here is the closest to the desired type I could get:

```
postulate t1 t2 : Set

A = ((t2 -> t1) -> t1) -> (((t2 -> t1) -> t1) -> t1) -> t1
B = (t2 -> t1) -> ((t2 -> t1) -> t1) -> t1
C = t1 -> t1

min : (A -> A) -> (B -> B) -> (C -> C)
min a b = \ f x -> a (\ p c -> c p) (\ c -> x) (b (\ p c -> f (c p)) (\ c -> x))
```

To work with Church-encoded nats `min` must accept two arguments of type `(a -> a) -> a -> a`, i.e. `A` must be of type `a -> a`, i.e.

```
a ~ (t2                 -> t1) -> t1
a ~ (((t2 -> t1) -> t1) -> t1) -> t1
```

i.e. `t2 ~ (t2 -> t1) -> t1`, which is a loop. There is no recursive types in System F or CoC and hence the term is not typeable as is.

However I ignored the `Rank2Types` stuff. Anyway,

```
newtype Church = Church { runChurch :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a }

min' a b = Church $ \f x -> runChurch a (\p c -> c p) (\c -> x) (runChurch b (\p c -> f (c p)) (\c -> x))
```

is an infinite type error as well.

Comment: See [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf) for discussion on `min`-like constructions.

Comment: @András Kovács, thanks, that's unusually readable paper that contains continuations. So we do need to solve `t2 = (t2 -> t1) -> t1` and thus do need recursive types.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, what do you think about [Self Types](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49638/do-self-types-make-the-calculus-of-inductive-constructions-obsolete)? Do it solve the problem without other issues?

Comment: @Viclib I think `min` could be typed in it after we do some extension to the system in the paper, specifically we need to compute types from `Nat`-s, which requires induction motive `Nat -> ☐`, but the paper only has `Nat -> *`. This shouldn't be too hard though, we could use a hierarchy of universes like in Agda/Coq, or `* : *` if we're lazy. The paper's a great find.

Comment: @András Kovács, the system already has `* : *`. But then we can just use Scott-encoded data. I don't think it's possible to typify `self k = k self` (which is the most basic thing that we can do with hyperfunctions) in any sound type system: `self self` is an immediate loop.

Comment: @user3237465: I only see `* : ☐` in [the paper](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/fu-stump-rta-tlca-14.pdf). As to typing `min`, we just need to supply extra proof that the types of the coroutining folds always line up. [See Agda code](http://lpaste.net/145786). On first look it seems to be feasible with "self types" too, if we add large elimination.

Comment: @András Kovács, I guess there is `* : ☐` in the paper only because of the erasion to System F-omega stuff. [The slides](http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/pengfu/document/talks/mvd-2012.pdf) contain `* : *`. The code is enlightening, thanks. It's impossible to define `self k = k self`, but not `self : ∀ n -> Min ⊤ n -> ℕ; self  0      k = k _; self (suc n) k = k (self n)`.

Comment: @Viclib, András Kovács, I wrote a more or less direct [translation](http://lpaste.net/145793) of coroutining folds to Agda.

Comment: @user3237465, I'm not sure I understand what you guys are talking about. What exactly is the conclusion? For `min` to be typed in a sound system, all we need is `self` and an infinite hierarchy of universes - is that what you said? I (very) superficially understand what your code is doing, but I don't see any self referential type there, so I'm not sure what this has to do.

Comment: @Viclib, `self`-types give you the induction principle, which is needed to define `foldK`. But with the induction principle you can write `min` using direct pattern matching. So yes, `self`-types give you the ability to make `min` typed, but they also give you the ability to write the usual three-lines definition of `min`. But I don't know whether self-types are really unproblematic.

Comment: @user3237465 you mean the usual recursive function? `min (S a) (S b) = min a b; min Z b = b; min a Z = a`? That doesn't make sense, because those need the Y-Combinator (even on the untyped lambda calculus), which can't be typed, right?

Comment: @Viclib, if `a` is Church-encoded and `b` is Scott-encoded, then you don't need the Y-combinator. Eliminators give you both like Parigot encoding. (We discussed this and I agreed that `min` defined this way is too strict, but that was wrong: [here](http://lpaste.net/145886) is the program that terminates immediately. With Church encoding you're stuck with `tail`, but not with `head`). [Here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Lists/zipWith-via-elim.agda) is `zipWith` defined in terms of eliminators.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I'll try to extend Morte with `self` and write your `foldK` there, that might be a great exercise. But what is going on on line 7, after the `=` sign? Why interleave uses `{}` instead of `()` on the arguments? Also, I'm not sure where `self` is used TBH, `foldK`'s type doesn't refer to itself, it refer's to `FoldK`...

Comment: @Viclib, I'd become convenient with dependent types before trying to implement a typechecker, especially with a non-well-known non-syntax-directed rules. `FoldK` makes a type of a continuation from a number. Implicit arguments are enclosed in `{}` — it's just a convenience, you can make everything explicit. The point about `foldK` is that its type depends on `n`. With Church-encoded nats there is no way to express this dependency — they give you the power of predicative System F (modulo large elimination). `self` gives you eliminators, which are the cornerstone of dependent type theories.