# How to type zipWith in Morte?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type, morte

This is an almost valid `zipWith` definition in Morte:

```
zipWith
  =  λ (u : *)
  -> λ (f : (u -> u -> u))
  -> λ (a : (#List u))
  -> λ (b : (#List u))
  -> λ (List : *)
  -> λ (cons : (u -> List -> List))
  -> λ (nil : List)
  -> ((λ (A:*) -> λ (B:*) ->
  (a (B -> List)
    (λ (h:u) -> λ (t : (B -> List) -> λ k : B -> (k h t)))
    (λ (k:B) -> nil)
    (b (u -> A -> List)
      (λ (h:u) -> λ (t:(u -> A -> List)) -> λ (H:u) -> λ (k:A) -> (cons (f h H) (k t)))
      (λ (H:u) -> λ (k:A) -> nil)))
  ) (fix A . ((u -> A -> List) -> List))
    (fix B . (u -> (B -> List) -> List)))
```

It isn't actually typeable due to the use of `fix`, which Morte lacks. [András posted this clever Agda solution without `fix`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930561/477476) last year. It isn't obvious to me how it translates to Morte, though, because it also lacks inductive types. How to approach this problem?

Edit: seems like my zipWith was incorrect even with `fix`. [This one](http://lpaste.net/341877) seems to check, though.

Answer (score 6):

I'll be using regular Haskell lists for simplicity. First, let's define `zipWith` using `foldr`:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys = foldr step (const []) xs ys where
  step x r  []    = []
  step x r (y:ys) = f x y : r ys
```

Here we fold over `xs`, pass `ys` as an argument and split it at each iteration. The problem is that we want to emulate Church-encoded lists, but they can't be pattern matched on. It is however possible to define `split`

```
split :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
split  []    = Nothing
split (x:xs) = Just (x, xs)
```

in terms of `foldr`:

```
split :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
split = snd . foldr (\x ~(r, _) -> (x : r, Just (x, r))) ([], Nothing)
```

Now we can define `zipWith` using only right folds:

```
czipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
czipWith f xs ys = foldr step (const []) xs ys where
  step x r = maybe [] (\(y, ys) -> f x y : r ys) . split
```

However while `split` traverses a list lazily (so `split [1..] ≡ Just (1, [2..])`), it nevertheless deconstructs and reconstructs an entire list, and hence each `split` introduces an O(n) overhead, where `n` is the length of the list being splitted. Since `ys` is splitted at each iteration, total complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2).

So yes, you can type `zipWith` using only non-recursive types, but it'll be O(n^2).

---

Also, eliminators are dependent paramorphisms and paramorphisms do give you pattern matching, so if you have eliminators, it's [straightforward](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Lists/zipWith-via-elim.agda) to define O(n) `zipWith`  and it doesn't have to be as complicated as in **András**' answer you linked.

Some reading:

- In a typed setting Church encoding is called [Boehm-Berarducci](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/Boehm-Berarducci.html) encoding.
- [How to zip folds](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/zip-folds.lhs).
- [How to take a TAIL of a functional stream](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/car-fstream.lhs).
- That definition of `split` in terms of `foldr` I'm using is described somewhere in [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/).

Answer (score 4):

The clever definition of `zipWith` (which comes from [Launchbury et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf), I believe) doesn't work in Morte, because typing it without negative recursive types (which Morte doesn't have, and which imply `fix`, as seen in my [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885983/infinite-type-error-when-defining-zip-with-foldr-only-can-it-be-fixed/29930561#29930561) previous answer) requires induction at least on natural numbers. [Here's](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/agda/Hyperfunction.agda) a simple Agda version of Launchbury's definition without Church encoding; to reproduce this in Morte we'd need functions whose return type depends on natural numbers (the lengths of input lists).

Without induction, the best we can do is an `O(N^2)` definition that uses `O(N)` pattern matching on lists, i. e. a `List A -> Maybe (A, List A)` function. It's `O(N)` because we can only get the tail of the list by rebuilding it from the end.

In Morte-compliant Agda (to get Morte, we need to desugar `let` style definitions to applications and function definitions to annotated lambdas):

```
Pair : Set → Set → Set
Pair A B = ∀ P → (A → B → P) → P

pair : ∀ A B → A → B → Pair A B
pair A B a b P p = p a b

List : Set → Set
List = λ A → ∀ L → (A → L → L) → L → L

Maybe : Set → Set
Maybe A = ∀ M → (A → M) → M → M

just : ∀ A → A → Maybe A
just A a M j n = j a

nothing : ∀ A → Maybe A
nothing A M j n = n

nil : ∀ A → List A
nil A L c n = n

cons : ∀ A → A → List A → List A
cons A a as L c n = c a (as L c n)

match : ∀ A → List A → Maybe (Pair A (List A))
match A as =
  as
    (Maybe (Pair A (List A)))
    (λ a m M j n →
       m M
         (λ p → p M (λ a' as → j (pair A (List A) a (cons A a' as))))
         (j (pair A (List A) a (nil A))))
    (nothing (Pair A (List A)))

zipWith : ∀ A B C → (A → B → C) → List A → List B → List C
zipWith A B C f as = 
  as
    (List B → List C)
    (λ a hyp bs → match B bs (List C)
      (λ p → p (List C) (λ b bs' → cons C (f a b) (hyp bs')))
      (nil C))
    (λ _ → nil C)
```