# How to fix the error ('cannot construct the infinite type') in my code and how to make my code work

Tags: list, haskell

Basically i'm trying to do a function where you are given a list and a number and you have to split the list in lists of the same size as the number given and the last split of all can have a length lower than the number given

```
separa a xs = if length xs >= a then separaM a (drop a xs) ([take a xs]) else [xs]

separaM a xs yss = if length xs >= a then separaM a (drop a xs) (yss : (take a xs)) else separaM a [] (yss : xs)
separaM a [] yss = yss
```

I expect the output of 3 "comovais" to be ["com","ova","is"] but in my program there is no output because of the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the expression:

```
yss : (take a xs)
```

`(take a xs)` has type `[b]`, so `yss` has type `b`. But when you pass `yss : (take a xs)` as an argument to `separaM` function, `yss` is expected has type `[b]` not `b`. That is why the error occurred.

Actually, you don't need `yss` to store the result, the recursive function can be defined as:

```
separaM _ [] = []
separaM a xs = (if length xs >= a then (take a xs) else xs) : 
               separaM a (drop a xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some errors in it.  Tweaking your misuse of `(:)` gets it to pass the type-checker:

```
separa a xs 
  | length xs >= a =  go a (drop a xs) [take a xs]
  | otherwise      =  [xs]
  where
  go a xs yss 
    | length xs >= a  =  go a (drop a xs) (yss ++ [take a xs]) 
                                  -- was: (yss : (take a xs))
    | otherwise       =  go a [] (yss ++ [xs])
                         -- was: (yss : xs)
  go a [] yss = yss
```

but it's better to further change it to

```
separa :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
separa a xs 
  | length xs >= a =  go a (drop a xs) [take a xs]
  | otherwise      =  [xs]
  where
  go a xs yss 
    | length xs >= a  =  go a (drop a xs) ([take a xs] ++ yss) 
    | otherwise       =  reverse ([xs] ++ yss)
```

It works:

```
> separa 3 [1..10]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
```

This is a common "build in reverse, then reverse when built" idiom, frequently seen in strict functional languages. Some of them allow for lists to be built in top-down, natural order, by a technique known as *tail-recursion modulo cons*. Haskell is lazy, and lets us build its lists in top-down manner naturally and easily, with the equivalent *guarded recursion*:

```
separa :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
separa a xs 
  | length xs >= a =  go a (drop a xs) [take a xs]
  | otherwise      =  [xs]
  where
  go a xs yss 
    | length xs >= a  =  --     go a (drop a xs) (yss ++ [take a xs]) 
                         yss ++ go a (drop a xs)         [take a xs] 
    | otherwise       =  -- go a [] (yss ++ [xs])
                         yss ++             [xs]
```

There's an off-by-one error here; I'll leave it for you to fix on your own.

---

But sometimes the infinite type is inherent to a problem, and not a result of a programming error. Then we can fix it by using recursive types.

Whenever we get type equivalency `t ~ a..b..t..c..`, we can start by defining a type

```
newtype T = MkT (a..b..T..c..)
```

then see which type variables are free and close over them, as

```
newtype T a b c = MkT (a..b..(T a b c)..c..)
```

An example: [Infinite type error when defining zip with foldr only; can it be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885983/infinite-type-error-when-defining-zip-with-foldr-only-can-it-be-fixed)