# Understanding Haskell function signature

Tags: haskell

I m new in haskell's world and I m having some troubles with function signatures :

What does it mean in simple worlds  :

```
add:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Does it mean that the two first parameters are `Integer` and the returned value is `Integer` too ?

Can you explain me, the aim of using arrows to determine a type of parameter or at least give me a brief explanation about this function signature ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Colloquially we may indeed refer to `add` as a function that takes two `Integer`s and produces an `Integer`. However to understand the notation, you need to understand that technically there's no such thing as a function that takes two arguments in Haskell.

Rather every function takes exactly one argument and the type of a function is written `a -> r` where `a` is the type of the argument and `r` is the type of the result. The function arrow is right-associative, which means that the type `a -> (b -> c)` can be written without parentheses as `a -> b -> c`.

So `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` is the same as `Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)`, which tells us that `add` is a function that takes an `Integer` and produces another function of type `Integer -> Integer`. This is known as currying and is the usual way to "encode" multi-argument functions in Haskell.

To call such a curried function, we can write `add 1 2`, which, because function application is left associative, is the same as `(add 1) 2`, first calling `add 1` to get a function of type `Integer -> Integer` and then applying that function to the argument `2`.

Answer (score 5):

As a simple mental model - yes, the thing after the last arrow is a return type, and everything else are parameters.

Signatures for 2-and-more-ary functions look this way because they are actually unary functions returning another 1-and-more-ary function.

In your case

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

Passing `add` an argument gives

```
add 3 :: (Integer -> Integer)
```

And `add 3 4`, therefore is just `Integer` type.

Comment: I guess, a reference to [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) and [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) for details wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes: it's exactly what it means. The last type is the return value, all others are arguments.

This is so for a very simple reason, namely: there's no such thing as multi-agrument function in Haskell. All functions are single-argument in reallity, function's general type being `a -> b`. Then we have something looking like multi-parameter functions thanks to **currying**. All you need to understand this are parentheses:

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

Which reads: `add` is a function which takes an `Integer` and returns a function `Integer -> Integer`. All parentheses sqeeze on the right-hand side here. On the contrary, when you apply, all parentheses squeeze on the left hand size, like so:

```
(add 5) 6
```

Which reads: apply  `add` to argument `5`. In return you'll get a function - then apply that function to `6` (the final result being `11`). We could equally well define it like so:

```
add :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
add x = \y -> x + y
```

So the fact that you can specify multiple arguments for a function is only a syntactic sugar so that you don't have to return all these lambdas down the road.

This very fact is also why we can do this:

```
add5 :: Integer -> Integer
add5 = (+5)
```