# How does indexed foldr work operationally?

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm having trouble comprehending the definition:

```
ifoldr :: Foldable f => (Int -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b
ifoldr f z xs = foldr (\ x g i -> i `seq` f i x (g (i+1))) (const z) xs 0
```

In particular, it seems to avoid space leaks by avoiding `zip [1..]` and at the same time it seems to derive a new fold "step function" that is given additional argument to front, but this argument is passed last in `\ x g i`!

Is this equivalent to `f' x (foldr f' z xs)` for some definition `f' = _unknown_ f` with retaining non-strictness properties?

Comment: It is worth thinking about what the specialized type of `foldr` is.  That is, `foldr :: (x -> y -> y) -> y -> [x] -> y` ; what are the types `x` and `y` here?  (For example `const z` has type `y`, so `y` must actually be a function type...)

Comment: The `foldr` itself does *not* create the elements, it creates a function, like the `State` does as well, and then calls it with `0` as parameter, and (more or less like `State`), it updates the state (although here that is done implicitly).

Comment: Yes, I can see that the result of the fold is a function, but I have trouble seeing how could this match the usual behavior of foldr where step function is the outer expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: the `foldr` produces a *function* (not a list of values), and that function will then generate that list.

Let us first ignore the `foldr` for a while, and concentrate on the function used in the foldr, let us call this function `eval`:

```
eval x g i = seq i (f i x (g (i+1))))
```

We will ignore the `seq` here: yes it has some semantics: evaluating (to *weak head normal form*) the `i` and checking if `i` is bottom, but let us assume that this will not introduce a bottom. So `eval` is - more or less - equivalent to:

```
eval x g i = f i x (g (i+1))
```

Now we can take the `foldr` context back into account:

```
ifoldr f = foldr eval (const z) xs 0
    where eval x g i = f i x (g (i+1))
```

Now `foldr` is defined (for lists, but let us keep things simple here), as:

```
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

For a list with three elements `[x1, x2, x3]`, this thus means that:

```
foldr eval (const z) [x1, x2, x3]
```

looks like:

```
-- foldr eval (const z) [x1, x2, x3] is equivalent to
eval x1 (eval x2 (eval x3 (const z)))
```

Since `eval` is defined as above, that means that we can specialize it to:

```
\i1 -> f i1 x1 ((\i2 -> f i2 x2 (\i3 -> f i3 x3 (const z)) (i2 + 1)) (i1 + 1))
```

Or perhaps in a way that makes the structure more clear:

```
\i1 -> (
    f i1 x1
    \i2 -> (
        f i2 x2
        \i3 -> (
            f i3 x3
            (const z) (i3+1)
        ) (i2+1)
    ) (i1+1)
)
```

So as you can see the outer function takes a parameter (here `i1`), and makes a call to `f` with `i1` (the index), `x1` (the first item), and as last item the result of a call that is the "fold" of the remaining list. We thus make a call with `i2` as parameter, but that `i2` is bound with `i1+1`.

So if we perform substitution (substuting `i3` with `i2 + 1`), which is how lambda calculus works, we obtain:

```
\i1 -> (
    f i1 x1
    \i2 -> (
        f i2 x2
        (
            f (i2+1) x3
            (const z) (i2+1+1)
        )
    ) (i1+1)
)
```

and furthermore we can substitute `i2` with `i1+1`:

```
\i1 -> (
    f i1 x1
    (
        f (i1+1) x2
        (
            f (i2+1) x3
            (const z) (i1+1+1+1)
        )
)
```

Since `(const z)` maps to `z`, regardless what the parameter is, we can substitute `(const z) (i1+1+1+1)` with `z`, so:

```
\i1 -> (
    f i1 x1
    (
        f (i1+1) x2
        (
            f (i1+1+1) x3
            z
        )
)
```

So now we know what `foldr eval (const z) [x1, x2, x3]` maps to, but there is a final fuction application: the `0` at the end.

So that means that we make a call to the above defined lambda-expression with `0`, so this collapses to:

```
\i1 -> (
    f i1 x1
    (
        f (i1+1) x2
        (
            f (i1+1+1) x3
            z
        )
) 0
```

and thus:

```
(
    f 0 x1
    (
        f (0+1) x2
        (
            f (0+1+1) x3
            z
        )
)
```

or in a compact form:

```
(f 0 x1 (f 1 x2 (f 2 x3 z)))
```

So we managed to inject indices in our solution.

Now the `seq` of course has a function: it will prevent making huge (left-recursive) expression trees for the index, instead of `((((1+1)+1)+1)+1)+1`, it will ensure that each time we increment it, it is immediately evaluated, so that we will never obtain `1+1+1`, but always `2+1`, and immidiately resolve it to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

If <sup>(as indeed it is)</sup>

```
foldr c n (x:xs) = c x (foldr c n xs)  :: t

c x r = ...    -- r: mnemonic: recursive result

c x r :: t , r :: t , n :: t          -- same t
```

then [surely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235148/implement-zip-using-foldr/26285107#26285107) <sup>(by eta-expansion)</sup>

```
foldr c n (x:xs) i = c x (foldr c n xs) i  :: t

c x r i = ...   -- c = (\ x r i -> ... )

c x r i :: t , r i :: t , n i :: t        -- same t
```

and so we can have

```
ifoldr f n (x:xs) = foldr c n (x:xs) i = c x (foldr c n xs) i    :: t
                                       = f i x (foldr c n xs i')  :: t

c x r i = f i x (r i') 

c x r i :: t , r i :: t , n i :: t , f i x :: t -> t
```

and that's exactly what you got there.