# foldr for squareOn - Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, higher-order-functions, fold

In my lecture, we had to define the function `squareOn` such that

[image: 1]

with `foldr`.
The answer was

```
 squareOn :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> a        
 squareOn = foldr (\x acc y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y) id
```

I undestand how `foldr` works, but I'm new at lambda expressions in Haskell. Is `acc` any type of function from Haskell? It would be nice if someone could explain how `squareOn` works. :)

Comment: `acc` is just a variable name like `x` and `y`. It's short for *accumulator*, and is quire common (idiomatic?) in Haskell

Comment: `acc` is not *any* type; it is specifically one of type `a -> a`, like `id`.

Comment: so, yes, `acc` is a function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sort-of advanced usage of `foldr`. Normally, we see `foldr` used as in

```
fun xs = foldr (\x acc -> something using x and acc) base xs
```

or equivalently

```
fun = foldr (\x acc -> something using x and acc) base
```

which corresponds to the following recursive function:

```
fun []     = base
fun (x:xs) = something using x and acc
   where acc = fun xs
```

Your case is a special case of this usage, where `base`, `acc`, and `something using x and acc` are *functions*. That is, we have

```
fun []     = \y -> base'
fun (x:xs) = \y -> something using x, acc, y
   where acc = \y -> fun xs y
```

Moving back to `foldr`, we get

```
fun = foldr (\x acc -> \y -> something using x, acc, y) (\y -> base')
```

which can also be written as

```
fun = foldr (\x acc y -> something using x, acc, y) (\y -> base')
```

where a somehow confusing three-argument function appears to be passed to `foldr`.

Your specific case,

```
squareOn = foldr (\x acc y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y) id
```

corresponds to the explicit recursion:

```
squareOn []     = id
squareOn (x:xs) = \y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y
   where acc = \y -> squareOn xs y
```

or

```
squareOn []     y = y
squareOn (x:xs) y = if y == x then x*x else squareOn xs y
```

which you should be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define this function without a lambda.

```
squareOn :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> a
squareOn = foldr f id
  where
    f x acc = g
      where
        g y | x == y = x * x
            | otherwise = acc y
```

Now it's become what `foldr` usually looks like. It takes a function taking two arguments `f` and an initial value `id`.

When you pass `[2, 4]` to `squareOn`, it'll be expanded to `foldr f id [2, 4]`, then `f 2 (f 4 id)` by the definition of `foldr`.

`f 4 id` returns a function that takes one argument `y` which returns `4 * 4` if `y` is `4`, and returns `id y` otherwise. Let's call this function `p`.

```
p y | 4 == y = 4 * 4
    | otherwise = id y
```

Now, `f 2 (f 4 id)` returns a function that takes one argument `y` which returns `2 * 2` if `y` is `2`, and returns `p y` otherwise. When you name it `q`, it'll be like this.

```
q y | 2 == y = 2 * 2
    | otherwise = p y
```

So `squareOn [2, 4] 3`, for example, is equivalent to `q 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever skipped those explicit arguments just made it unnecessarily harder on yourself to learn this stuff. It's totally superficial. Adding the explicit arguments, as specified by the type signature, gives us

```
squareOn :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> a
squareOn      = foldr (\x acc y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y) id
squareOn xs   = foldr (\x acc y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y) id xs
squareOn xs y = foldr (\x acc y -> if y == x then x*x else acc y) id xs y
squareOn xs y = foldr g id xs y   where { g x acc y | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc y }
squareOn xs y = (case xs of { 
    []      -> id ;
    (x:xs2) -> g x (foldr g id xs2)
                          })  y   where { g x acc y | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc y }
```

Now we can *see* everything in play here, as opposed to having to keep it all in mind. There is playing chess, and then there's playing *blindfold* chess, and why play it blindfolded if you can just see?

So now it becomes obvious that [passing that `y` around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285107/849891)<sup>(*)</sup> from call to call *unchanged* actually has no purpose here, because it is the same `y`, and it is already in scope:

```
squareOn xs y = (case xs of { 
    []      -> y  ;
    (x:xs2) -> g x (foldr g y  xs2)
                          })      where { g x acc   | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc   }
```

which simplifies back as just

```
squareOn xs y = foldr g y  xs     where { g x acc   | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc   }
{- cf.
squareOn xs y = foldr g id xs y   where { g x acc y | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc y } -}
```

And to be pointlessly short and pointfree, like your original code,

```
squareOn      = flip (foldr g)    where { g x acc   | y == x    = x*x 
                                                    | otherwise = acc   }
```

Or it could be simplified to

```
squareOn xs y =  case xs of { 
    []             -> y   ;
    (x:_) | y == x -> x*x ;
    (_:xs2)        -> squareOn xs2 y }
```

and further to a worker/wrapper with nested unary worker, whichever is clearer for you.

Passing the unchanged quantity around to have it in scope is only really needed in languages without nested scope, like Prolog.

<sup>(*)</sup><sub>(so that explanation in full, which you asked for, about how this technique works, is actually in the linked answer).</sub>