# Defining my own isPrefixOf without recursion using foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I am working on a programming assignment where I must define my own version of `isPrefixOf` from `Data.List` using only `foldr`, `map`, and cons (and thus no recursion). The hint I've been given is that the return value of `foldr` should itself be a function. Can someone help me understand how I could apply that fact? My guess for the structure is included below.

```
startsWith :: String -> String -> Bool
startsWith s1 s2 = (foldr (???) ??? s1) s2
```

I am allowed to define my own helper functions. For the curious this is from an assignment for CIS 552 at Penn.

Comment: Do you have any permission to solve this problem with foldl ?

Comment: @S4eed3sm, a left fold has a particular performance issue with this problem.

Comment: Yes, you've started along the right path. I urge you to replace the first `???` with `_c` and the second one with `_n` and compile your module. GHC will tell you the types of the values that you need to put in the "holes".

Comment: First, figure out which function should `foldr` return when the length of s1 is zero. (That's easy: one that always returns `True` for any argument). Replace the second set of `???` with it. Then, figure out which function should `foldr` return when the length of s1 is n+1, and you already have a function that works correctly when the length is n.

Comment: @dfeuer Why foldl has performance issue here ?

Comment: @s4eed3sm, `foldl` and `foldl'` for lists can't short-circuit, so they'll walk the whole prefix even if there's a mismatch early on.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: It turns out that by folding over the pattern instead of the string, the code gets a lot simpler and shorter and something like

```
"" `isPrefixOf` undefined
```

works. Thank you @dfeuer and @WillNess. This is the updated program:

```
isPrefixOf pattern s = foldr g (const True) pattern s
    where
        g x r (h:t)
          | x == h    = r t
          | otherwise = False
```

It works almost the same way as the below program, so refer to that for the explanation.

---

I managed to solve it using nothing but `foldr`:

```
isPrefixOf :: String -> String -> Bool
p `isPrefixOf` s = isPrefixOfS p
    where
        isPrefixOfS 
            = foldr 
                (\c acc -> 
                    \str -> case str of
                        x:xs -> if c == x
                                then acc xs
                                else False
                        []   -> True 
                    )
                null
                s
```

Here's the explanation.

In order to create the function `isPrefixOf`, we want this:

```
isPrefixOf pattern s 
  = case pattern of
      [] -> True
      x:xs -> if (null s) then False
              else if (head s) /= x
                   then False
                   else xs `isPrefixOf` (tail s)
```

Well, let's simplify this - let's create a function called `isPrefixOfS` that only takes a pattern, which it compares to `s` automatically. We need to build this chain of nested functions:

```
-- Pseudocode, not actual Haskell

\p -> case p of 
        [] -> True
        x:xs -> if x /= (s !! 0)
                  then False
                  else <apply xs to> \q -> case q of [] -> True
                                                     x:xs -> if x /= (s !! 1) -- Note that we've incremented the index
                                                             then False
                                                             else <apply xs to> \r -> ....
```

This seems pretty self explanatory - let me know in a comment if it requires further explanation.
Well, we can see that this chain has a recursive property to it, where the last character of `s` will be compared in the most deeply nested lambda. So we need to nest lambdas from right to left. What can we use for that? `foldr`.

```
isPrefixOfS 
            = foldr -- Folding from right to left across `s`
                (\c acc -> -- `c` is the current character of `s`, acc is the chain of nested functions so far
                    \str -> -- We return a function in the fold that takes a String
                      case str of
                        -- If the string is not null:
                        x:xs -> if c == x   -- If the head of the string is equal to the current character of s,
                                then acc xs -- Then pass the tail of the string to the nested function which will compare it with subsequent characters of s
                                else False -- Otherwise we return false
                
                        -- If the string is null, we have completely matched the prefix and so return True
                        []   -> True  
                    )
                null -- Innermost nested function - we need to make sure that if the prefix reaches here, it is null, i.e. we have entirely matched it
                s
```

And now we use this function `isPrefixOfS` on `p`:

```
p `isPrefixOf` s = isPrefixOfS p
```

**EDIT**: I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235208/17592995) which uses a similar logic to implement `zip` in terms of `foldr`, you may want to look at that as well.

Comment: Slight abbreviation: `c == x && acc xs`

Comment: Your answer is actually a little more complicated than it needs to be, and as a result also slightly wrong. ``[] `isPrefixOf` undefined`` should be `True`, but your code says `undefined`. Do you see why?

Comment: @dfeuer For your first comment - that was actually my original code but I made it a bit more verbose to expose the logic behind it. For the second comment - I didn't notice that, thanks for pointing it out. A simple pattern match in the definition of `isPrefixOf` will fix it. What in the program is too complicated?

Comment: indeed `and $ zipWith (==) [] undefined` returns `True` as does your second definition, so the first isn't its true translation. the straight-away translation of the 2d version folds over the first argument just like its prototype does: `isPrefixOf pattern s = foldr g (const True) pattern s where g x r (h:t) | x==h = r t | otherwise = False`. switching what is folded over first indeed complicates things.

Comment: Thanks @WillNess, your version of the function makes a lot more sense. I've edited the answer

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep and couldn't answer your question; glad you got it figured out. Patterns like `if ... then ... else False` are often seen in beginner code, but I am not convinced they're easier to understand.

Comment: This is a bit too much detail for someone's homework question. You want to guide them, not do their homework for them.